# open Expansion panel programitacally without clicking

Tags: angular, angular-material, expansion

is there any way to trigger the openAll method...so that i can open all panel programitacally ...
using openAll method...
i tried making a function then calling that function in ngOnint then it throws some error

> ERROR
> Error: Cannot read property 'openAll' of undefined

please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJXPO.png)

Html

```
    <mat-accordion class="example-headers-align" multi>
<!-- #enddocregion multi -->
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Personal data
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="number" min="1">
    </mat-form-field>

  </mat-expansion-panel>
<!-- #docregion disabled -->
  <mat-expansion-panel>
<!-- #enddocregion disabled -->
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Destination
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
      <input matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

> .ts file

```
import {Component, ViewChild, OnInit, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit, AfterContentChecked} from '@angular/core';
import {MatAccordion} from '@angular/material/expansion';

/**
 * @title Accordion with expand/collapse all toggles
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'expansion-expand-collapse-all-example',
  templateUrl: 'expansion-expand-collapse-all-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['expansion-expand-collapse-all-example.css'],
})
export class ExpansionExpandCollapseAllExample implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild(MatAccordion) accordion: MatAccordion;

  ngOnInit(){
   this.openPanel()
  }
 openPanel(){
    this.accordion.openAll()
 }
}
```

see below image

Comment: Angular fires `ngOnInit` when instance of component is created. You need to replace `ngOnInit` with `ngAfterViewInit`. Which fires when the content is initialized.

Comment: replace? can you tell me how i can replace that becuase when i am calling that function in ngAfterViewInit it throws the same error

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't response your previous comment. You are welcome!